# Can I distinguish touchpad and mouse messages within a low level hook proc? (Win32)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, hid

I am working on adding touchpad-specific functionality to a windows desktop application (written in C/C++). Here are my requirements:

1. The user shall be able to use both a standard windows mouse and touchpad simultaneously.
2. All touchpad HID events shall be custom-handled by the application as long as it is running. It shall not be able to control the mouse or interact with other windows.
3. Normal mouse operation shall not be affected when a touchpad is in use.

Through researching the Win32 API, I learned that a [low level mouse hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)) could be used to block touchpad/mouse input from the rest of the system. I got a message queue and simple hook proc working.

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK lowLevelHIDHookProc
    (
    int                 nCode,
    WPARAM              wParam,
    LPARAM              lParam
    )
{
HHOOK ignored( NULL );

// have to pass message along to next hook
if( nCode < 0 )
    {
    return( CallNextHookEx( ignored, nCode, wParam, lParam ) );
    }
// THIS IS WHAT I CAN'T FIGURE OUT
else if( eventComingFromNormalMouse ) // allow normal mouse events
    {
    return( CallNextHookEx( ignored, nCode, wParam, lParam ) );
    }
// block touchpad stuff here
else
    {
    printf( "********\nTOUCH INTERCEPTED!!!\n********\n" );
    return( -1 );
    }
```

What I'm stuck on right now is distinguishing mouse messages coming from touchpads and normal mice. I found a couple open source projects and examples that use HID [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-raw-input?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in order to detect and read generic touchpad data, but they are fine with the mouse cursor being disabled while the touchpad is in use. Instead, I need to figure out in this hook proc whether the message is being generated by a touchpad device, and only block in that case, so the mouse can work normally.

I'm looking through the [lParam/MSLLHOOKSTRUCT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct?redirectedfrom=MSDN#members), but am not seeing anything that looks helpful for making this distinction. I'm open to any ideas, including not using low-level hooks at all since they have a performance impact. Maybe there's a way to open a serial connection to a USB touchpad without windows detecting it as an HID device at all?

Comment: You're trying way too hard. Just ask for `WM_TOUCH` messages and the system won't generate back-compat mouse messages for touch input.

Comment: @IInspectable our application makes use of touchscreen monitor-generated WM_TOUCH events, the handling of which I don't want to interfere with. Also, I think WM_TOUCH is restricted to when the app is active; I want to receive touchpad data unconditionally. But it looks like you're right, I was being dumb. Registering for raw input would also prevent the touchpad from sending mouse messages and solve my problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetWindowsHookEx()` hooks, like `WH_MOUSE_LL`, do not provide any identifying information about the devices that are generating input events.  Raw Input hooks can identify devices, but they can't block input events.

So, you will have to use both kinds of hooks and coordinate them - use a Raw Input hook to identify the touchpad events, and use a `WH_MOUSE` (not `WH_MOUSE_LL`) hook to block the events.

However, this is not easy to do *reliably*.  See [Combining Raw Input and keyboard Hook to selectively block input from multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective) <sup>1</sup> for more info, and gotchas.

<sup>1: that article was written for keyboard input, but should be applicable to mouse/touchpad input, too.</sup>

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply. I did find that resource, as well as the Interception API (https://github.com/oblitum/Interception) which seems to address the same limitation. I don't think I'll have to pursue that option though. I didn't realize that registering for raw input would prevent mouse movement.

Comment: @DannyLovell "*registering for raw input would prevent mouse movement*" - what do you mean? I've never heard about that before.

Comment: Apparently, registering for Raw Input from a digitizer prevents the system from generating the compatibility mouse messages. I wasn't aware of this either. If that is indeed the case, @dan should post an answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right. This is not how it works. I'll need to use some type of mouse hook still.